# Show the $i$-th row of $D_f$ is $\nabla f_i$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the $i$-th row of the differential, $D_f$ is the gradient of $i$-th function, $\nabla f_i$

I understand it intuitively, because I know that $(D_f)_{ij} = \frac{df_i}{x_j}$

But somehow I wasn't able to write it down formally. I'd be glad for help with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $(\nabla f_i)_j=\partial f_i/\partial x_j$, and as you know this $(D_f)_{ij}$, where the subscript $j$ denotes the $j$-th component.

Comment: You used the definition, but I think the question asks to prove it.

Comment: In that case I think you should make this clear, the way I read your question is that you know this (i.e. the Jacobian represents the differential), but are confused about notation.